# How to solve this limit with x tending to 4

Tags: real-analysis

How to solve:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 4} \left(\frac{x+6}{x^2-16}-\frac{x+1}{x^2-4x}\right)$$

Without Hopital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your term $$\frac{x+6}{x^2-16}-\frac{x+1}{x^2-4x}$$ simplifies to $$\frac{1}{4x+x^2}$$

Comment: Hint? Solution, I’d say :/

Comment: But i have not written the steps!

Comment: There is that, at least. I suppose between the two of us, we have supplied everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Factor the denominators, find the least common denominator, and add the fractions. Then simplify and factor the numerator of that sum. With luck, there will be a factor of $(x-4)$ in the new numerator which will cancel the same troublesome factor in the common denominator.